# Call another another application then back to the same application opened previously

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an android application A and android application B.
I want to call application B from application A and get some data from application B and return back to same application A which was opened previously.

Application A

```
Intent app = new Intent(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
app.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.abc.applicationA","com.abc.applicationA.MainActivity"));
startActivity(applicationA);
```

Application B

```
Intent j = new Intent(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
j.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.abc.applicationB","com.abc.applicationB.MainActivity"));
j.putStringArrayListExtra("Data", data); //data is array list
startActivity(j);
```

But for the above implementation applicationA launches applicationB then again when applicationB launches applicationA once more time the applciationA is launched.so when i go back i will have applicationA which is called second time,then applicationB and applicationA called 1st time.

My intention is applicationA is launched and then go to applicationB get some data and come back to same applicationA launcehed before.

Comment: How about using AIDL and services

Comment: `startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 0):

As cricket says, `startActivityForResult` is the correct answer here. In activity A, you open Activity B by calling `startActivityForResult` on Activity B. Then when you are finished in Activity B, you will call the `setResult`  function and then `finish()`.

Comment: i am able to traverse from applicationA to Application B and get back applicationA without getting applicationA called twice,but i also want to access applicationA in applicationB which i am not able to do it.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by " i also want to access applicationA in applicationB ". My interpretation of your question is that you want this...

Comment: From Activity A in App A start Activity B in App B for result. When you are finished in Activity B in Application B, you setResult, and then call finish(), which should return you to Activity A in App A with the result you want.

Comment: If this is not what you want, please update your question. Also, please update the code to the newest version that you are testing so that we are on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

In ApplicationA,

Try using `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`.

```
int REQUEST_CODE = *any Integer as request code*
Intent app = new Intent(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
app.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.abc.applicationB","com.abc.applicationB.MainActivity"));
startActivityForResult(applicationA,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Also override `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        //check the resultCode and data would contain the extras
    }
}
```

In ApplicationB, use `setResult()` method.

Comment: I think this should be changed `app.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.abc.applicationB","com.abc.applicationB.MainActivity"));`

Comment: i am able to traverse from applicationA to Application B and get back applicationA without getting applicationA called twice,but i also want to access applicationA in applicationB which i am not able to do it.